# Create/Update Duplicate Detection - Only check against contacts with fieldX = true

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, duplicate-detection

We have a lot of contacts in CRM 2011 which are imported to support a legacy application. All these contacts have a field which is set to be true to indicate that we don't show these on any of the views.

I am looking at a way to exclude these from the Create/Update duplicate detection that can be enabled on contacts.

These contacts are currently read only so for now my solution is to deactivate those records so I can use the 'exclude de-activated records' option.

This feels like a bit of a hack, is there not a way of telling the duplicate detection which sub set of contacts to check against?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deactivating would definitely be one way to get around it.  If you don't want them deactivated, you can migrate that field to another field that dupe checking is allowed on since CRM doesn't allow dupe checking on two option fields, and then use an exact match on that field instead.

If you don't have a ton of records in that subset, you can do an advanced find and bulk edit the new field 250 records at a time.

Comment: I did actually try this but it only allows me to match on that field where they are the same, I actual want to exclude them completely for the matching as they are irrelevant

Comment: By matching on exact mach it should exclude those records.  Set the value on all the records you want to include in the dupe detection to match on and it should only return those records, and it should exclude the ones you don't want.  It is similar to the logic for deactivating them.  Match where record1.statecode = record2.statecode.  If record2.statecode is inactive then it won't match.

Comment: But we may have 5 duplicates all deactivated (fieldValue=x), and 2 active (fieldValue=y) so not sure that would work?

Answer (score 0):

through user interface i don't know any method to do that, but you can launch the duplicate detection through plugin or via javascript (example ribbon button) and control the records that is returned. Check this [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh547456.aspx) that you can replicate in a plugin.

Comment: While this may answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include more of the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.